# ForgeJs ThreeJs Error -GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete

Tags: three.js, forge

I am using threeJs and ForgeJs to rotate a panorama in 360 view .
But when Loading the page it showing the warning messages in console like this..

```
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE7AD0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C687EE9DB0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glClear: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete
moderator.php?id=331:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001C6871F54B0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
```

How can I stop OR remove this warning.
due this warning page is loading very slow and its also hanged some time.

Comment: your textures are probably too large

Comment: How can I solve this ?